# Create Table SQL Syntax Error - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

Verified sql syntax code with http://sqlformat.appspot.com/ and its still not working....

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE test (prime_key AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, train_num INT, train_type CHAR(50))";
```

Its giving me "near 'AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY...'" in the error message. What am I missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Check the documentation instead of a SQL formatter for proper syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an underscore `_`, not a dash (`-`). You're also missing a data type for your `prime_key` column:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
  ( 
     prime_key  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
     train_num  INT, 
     train_type CHAR(50) 
  )
```

Comment: +1 for your ability properly create a table.

Comment: +1 for your ability to comment.

Comment: I'm closing this tab before this becomes a vicious whirlwind of +1 for the ability to to basic things.

Comment: Thanks guys! Sorry for being a noob

Answer (score 1):

It is [**`AUTO_INCREMENT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) not `AUTO-INCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

The error is, technically spoken, caused by `AUTO-INCREMENT` not being a valid column type.